# How to create an UIImage from the contents of a SpriteView

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit

I'd like to ultimately save a SpriteView as a photo. The issue is that I'm going nowhere with it. For clarity `GridView` is essentially an SKScene which is then wrapped by a SpriteView in `WallpaperView`.

If I try to use `ImageRenderer` in wallpaper view directly I get `Unable to render flattened version of PlatformViewRepresentableAdaptor<UIKitSpriteKitView>.`

And in the example below, I get a 30x30 image with, yellow background and red X.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

```
struct WallpaperView: View {
    let grid = Grid(density: 256, contents: ["1", "2", "3", "4"])
    let cellSizeRange: ClosedRange<CGFloat> = (1...4)
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            SpriteView(scene: GridView(grid: grid, cellSizeRange: cellSizeRange, size: geometry.size))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let wallpaperView = WallpaperView()
        ZStack {
            wallpaperView
            Button("Export", action: {
                let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: wallpaperView)
                renderer.scale = 3
                let image = renderer.uiImage
                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SKView's [`texture(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skview/1520114-texture) to render the contents of the `SKScene` (GridView) into an `SKTexture` and then use SKTexture's [`cgImage()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sktexture/1519755-cgimage) in an [`UIImage(cgImage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624090-init).

Something like this:

```swift
guard let texture = gridView.view?.texture(from: gridView) else { return UIImage() }
return UIImage(cgImage: texture.cgImage())
```

Comment: This absolutely worked! Thanks a ton!